# How to round out the tip of a cone

Tags: modeling

How can I round out the tip of this cone to make it look like an airplane nose?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far? I would suggest you take a look at [proportional editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html).

Comment: Using Subdivision Surface modifier for specific Vertex Group?

Comment: You could also try with a sphere and work back from that

Comment: Collapse the outermost vertex. Extrude the flat circular face left. Scale it down a little bit. Bevel it with several segments to get your rounded nose.

Answer (score 9):

Just to illustrate how to use proportional editing here.

1. Add more loopcuts
2. Move the tip inwards
3. Check *Proportional editing > Sharp* and adjust

[image]

Comment: ? Sharp ... what a trick :)

Comment: Just tried the falloff types until one worked :) my usual method :))

Comment: :) ... with you is my day somehow always better :)

Comment: cant loop cut a cone

Comment: Hey @guppie :). Just select edges around and subdivide. That's how i did it on my cone.

Answer (score 1):

I've had more experience modeling with CAD tools that use the addition/subtraction of geometric shapes to build up a mesh.

If I was doing this in CAD, I'd round out the nose using something like the following:

[image]

1. Create a sphere with the radius that you want for the tip of your cone.
2. Position the sphere such that its surface is tangent to the cone.
3. Subtract the portion of the cone surface from the vertex to the point where it intersects with the sphere. You can also remove the lower portion of the sphere, if it matters.

Comment: I'd actually prefer this approach myself :). It allows a better control of the radius, and better topology if you use a quadsphere :))